# An exercise about drawing a rectangle class using the printf function

Tags: printf

So the problem is the following :

"Write a method for the Rectangle class called draw that draws a rectangle using dashes and vertical bar characters. The following code sequence

```
Rectangle *myRect = [[Rectangle alloc]init];
[myRect setWidth : 10 andHeight : 3];
[myRect draw];
```

Would produce the following output : "

(i cant show you the picture but its a rectangle made out of "-" dashes and "|" bar characters. Dashes are for width and bar characters for height.)

I've started doing the method like this :

```
{
int n;

for ( n = 1 ; n <= self.width ; ++n)
    printf ("-");

for ( n = 1 ; n <= self.height ; ++n){
    printf ("\n|");
        }
    printf("\n");

for ( n = 1 ; n <= self.width ; ++n){
    printf ("-");
}
```

But it seems like its not going to work like that , i cant get it to display the outer (|) lines . Could anyone help me on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are working in Objective-C, but here is a simple set of code that i tested in C that should translate over very easily:

```
void printRectangle(int width, int height)
{
     int n;
     int z;

     printf(" ");

     for (n = 1 ; n <= width ; n++)
        printf ("-");

     printf("\n");

     for ( n = 1 ; n <= height ; n++)
     {
        printf ("|");

        for(z = 1; z <= width; z++)
             printf(" ");

        printf("|\n");
     }

     printf(" ");

     for ( n = 1 ; n <= width ; ++n)
         printf ("-");

     printf("\n");
}
```

Output for width = 10, height = 5

```
 ----------
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
 ----------
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't see the accepted answer above. However, I will leave this up just incase.

I haven't tested it in objective C. But give it a go :)

```
for (int y = 0; y <= self.width; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= self.width; x++) {
        if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == self.width || y == self.height) {
            if (y == 0 || y == self.height) {
                printf("-");
            }
            else if (x == 0 || x == self.width) {
                printf("|");
            }
            if (x == 10) {
                printf("\n");
            }
        } else {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
  }
```

This was written in java and I just changed some words to match yours. :)

Output:

```
-----------
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
-----------
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative solution. The first answer was the solution i was looking for , but this is very interesting as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  Created by Victor Diaz  on 11/10/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Victor Diaz . All rights reserved.
//  lines of code are submitted but  i have just inputed here the function draw

-(void)draw{
    int i=0;
    printf(" ");
    for(i=0; i<=width;i++){
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<=height;i++){
        printf("|");
        for (int z=0; z<width; z++)
            printf(" ");
            printf(" |\n");
    }
    printf(" ");
    for (i=0; i<=width; i++) {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
@end
```